# Equation for inverted mirrored $\ln(x)$ for $x<1$?

Tags: functions, logarithms, graphing-functions

[image]

Is there a simple equation for this curve? It uses $\ln(x)$ model for $x>1$ (I removed the $\ln$ part below zero) and something like inverted/mirrored $\ln(x)$ for $x<1$. It's not $\arctan(x)$ because it scales differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that exact function, you should write it as
$$
f(x) = \cases{\ln(x) & if $x>1$\\-\ln(2-x) & otherwise}
$$
For $x>1$ we have $\ln$, and for all the other values of $x$, we have mirrored it horizontally (as we can see from the $-x$), and mirrored it vertically (as we can see from the $-\ln$). (The $2$ in $2-x$ adjusts the axis of the horizontal reflection, so that we reflect about $x = 1$, not $x = 0$.)

Answer (score 1):

Another representation:
$$
\log\left(\frac{(x-1)_+^2-1}{x-2}\right)
$$
where $(\dots)_+$ is the [positive part function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_and_negative_parts):
$$
(x)_+=\frac{|x|+x}2
$$

Comment: That's a cool one! I like that the piecewise part is hidden in the absolute value. So, after substitution we get:
$$\log\Big(\frac{(x-3+|x-1|)(x+1+|x-1|)}{4x-8}\Big)$$

Answer (score 0):

The mirrored part is

$$-\ln (2-x)$$